# Change Unity Mscorlib

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mscorlib

So currently, Unity (2017.3) is referencing mscorlib, however it's very outdated in the fact that it references mscorlib version 2.0.0.0. How can I change this so I have a newer version? Say mscorlib version 4.0.0.0?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so basically I've been researching online and it turns out that .Net Framework 4.6 is still experimental with Unity. However if you want a newer mscorlib (in my case). You need to go in Unity -> File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Currently Script Runtime version by default is set to 3.6 (Stable) but you can change to 4.6 (Experimental)! Hopes this helps someone!